# General solution or approximate solution

Tags: polynomials, roots, fractions

Is there a known general or approximate explicit solution for $\xi$ in 
$$(1+\xi)^m (1-\xi)^n = C$$
 where $m$ and $n$ positive fractions and $C$ being constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THEOREM.

The equation 
$$
aqx^p+x^q=1\tag 1
$$
admits root $x$ such that 
$$
x^n=\frac{n}{q}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{\Gamma(\{n+pk\}/q)(-q a)^k}{\Gamma(\{n+pk\}/q-k+1)k!}\textrm{, }n>0\tag 2
$$
where $\Gamma(x)$ is Euler's the Gamma function. (Note that the root of $(1)$, for no confusion is given from $(2)$ with $n=1$).

Here the sum $(2)$ is valid for all real numbers $n,p$ and $q$ and for complex $a$ with
$$
|a|\leq |p|^{p/q}|p-q|^{(p-q)/q}.\tag 3
$$

$\ldots$ You want to solve the equation 
$$
(1+\xi)^m(1-\xi)^n=C.\tag 4
$$ 
Set $1+\xi=x$, then $(4)$ becomes $x^m(1-(x-1))^n=C$ or $x^m(2-x)^n=C$. Hence $x^{m/n}(2-x)=C^{1/m}$ or $2-x=C^{1/m}x^{-m/n}$. Hence $2x^{-1}-1=C^{1/m}x^{-m/n-1}$. Setting  $2x^{-1}=y$ we have $y-1=\frac{C^{1/m}}{2^{m/n+1}}y^{m/n+1}$ 
or 
$$
-C_1y^A+y=1,\tag 5
$$
where $C_1=-C^{1/m}2^{-m/n-1}$, $A=m/n+1$ and 
$$
\xi=2/y-1.\tag 6
$$
Hence using $(1),(2)$ we can extract a solution of $(5)$ and hence of $(4)$.

Comment: Bagis, could you give me reerence to (1) and (2) ?

Comment: References: 1) Bruce C. Berndt. "Ramanujan Notebooks I". Springer Verlag New York Inc (copyright) 1985. (Chapter: Ramanujan's Quarterly Reports. pg. 306-307). You will find there also further references to search.

Comment: Bagis, I can not verify the method as of now, but the solution does provide explicit solution as requested for

Comment: Can you give me more details. Where did you stack? Maybe I can help you someway.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

As  $-1 < \xi < 1$ consider $\xi = \cos x$ then following

$$
1-\cos x = 2\sin^2(\frac x2)\\
1+\cos x = 2\cos^2(\frac x2)
$$

we have

$$
\sin^{2n}(\frac x2)\cos^{2m}(\frac x2) = \frac{C}{2^{n+m}}
$$

now making considerations over the $\sin^{2n}(\frac x2)\cos^{2m}(\frac x2)$ extrema ...

Answer (score 1):

Since $m$ and $n$ are fractions, you can take the LCM of their
denominators and write
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  m = {p \over L}\quad n = {q \over L}\quad \left| {\;p,q,L \in N} \right. \hfill \cr 
  \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,p} \left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,q}  = C^{\,L}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
so that we can always reduce the problem to integral powers.

The approach I deem might work better is the following

Let's change the sign of the second term, so as to have a *monic* polynomial
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left( {x + 1} \right)^{\,p} \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,q}  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,q} C^{\,L}  = c\quad \left| {\;p,q,L \in N} \right.
}\tag{1}$$

Let's then consider that
$$
\left( {x + 1} \right)^{\,p} \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,q}  = \left\{ {\matrix{
   {\left( {x^{\,2}  - 1} \right)^{\,p} \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,q - p} } & {0 \le q - p}  \cr 
   {\left( {x^{\,2}  - 1} \right)^{\,q} \left( {x + 1} \right)^{\,p - q} } & {0 < p - q}  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$

We can therefore concentrate to examine
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  f(x,y) = \left( {x^{\,2}  - 1} \right)^{\,s} \left( {y - 1} \right)^{\,t}  = c \hfill \cr 
  y = x \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad \left| {\;s,t \in N} \right.
$$
that is
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  y = 1 + \left( {{c \over {\left( {x^{\,2}  - 1} \right)^{\,s} }}} \right)^{\,1\,/\,t}  \hfill \cr 
  y = x \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
where it is easy to define the domain of existence according to the sign
of $x^2-1,\; s, \; c, \; t$, and a sketch surely helps to focus the situation.
For example

[image: (x+1)^n(x-1)^m_1]

The sketch clearly indicates that in this case (and for other $s$ and $t$ with same parity)
we will have only one solution for positive $c$, and one or three for negative $c$.

It also tells us how we can compute the solution(s) by any of the classical
methods of iterative approximations, and where it is appropriate to place the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

First I thought, by deriving the general solution was $\xi=\frac{m-n}{m+n}$.

But for a solution with given $C$, I'd first reformulate the problem to $(1+\xi)(1-\xi)^a=c'$ with $a=n/m>0$ and $c'=c^{\frac{1}{m}}$...

Comment: I am not sure, this seems like finding the maximum/minimum of the function than providing the general solution

Comment: Hm yes, it solves for an arbitrary constant C, not for a given one.

Comment: Sorry I could not help

Answer (score 0):

Let WLOG 
$$(m,n)\in\mathbb N^2\tag1$$
and
$$(1+\xi)^m(1-\xi)^n=C.\tag2$$

So
$$m\log(1+\xi)+n\log(1-\xi)=\log C,\quad x\in(-1,1).\tag3$$
Note that
$$\lim_{x\to\pm1}LHS(3) = -\infty.$$
Maximum of $LHS(3)$ achieves when
$$\dfrac m{1+\xi} -\dfrac n{1-\xi}=0,$$
and that gives
$$\xi_m=\dfrac{m-n}{m+n}, \quad \max LHS(2) = \left(\dfrac {2m}{m+n}\right)^m\left(\dfrac {2n}{m+n}\right)^n.$$
Thus, the solution of $(2)$ exists only if
$$C \in\left[0,\dfrac{2^{m+n}m^mn^n}{(m+n)^{m+n}}\right].$$
If $\xi\not = \xi_m,$ then there are two solutions of $(2),$ which can be calculated using the iteration formulas
$$\xi_0 = -1,\quad \xi_{i+1}=1-C(1+\xi_i)^{-\frac mn}$$
for the less root and 
$$\xi_0=1,\quad \xi_{i+1}=C(1-\xi_i)^{-\frac nm}-1$$
for the greater root.